# Calculate time difference in milli seconds:

Tags: bash, shell

INPUT & OUTPUT ERROR:

```
14:00:11,320      14:00:11,453 
**Correct Output** :  Time difference is 133 milli seconds.

14:00:13,097       14:00:13,124 
**Output in Error** :  line 4: 124000000 - 097000000: value too great for base (error token is "097000000")  

14:00:11:693      14:00:13:048 
**Output in Error** :  line 4: 048000000: value too great for base (error token is "048000000")
```

Script Used:

```
g=$(( $(date -d $b +%s) - $(date -d $a +%s) ))
h=$(( $(date -d $b +%N) - $(date -d $a +%N) ))
k=$(( (g * 1000) + (h / 1000000) ))
printf "Total time difference: %i milli seconds\n"  $k
```

Comment: What ever were those tags about? There's no awk, sed or Perl in sight, and this isn't really about Linux in particular. Though if you are running RHEL, you probably are using Bash, so I'll tag that.

Answer (score 5):

You are right that this math fails under bash and most other shells, since they follow the C convention where a number starting with `0` is *octal*, not decimal:

```
$ echo "$((124000000 - 097000000))"
bash: 124000000 - 097000000: value too great for base (error token is "097000000")
```

One solution is to properly identify the numbers to bash as being base-10:

```
$ echo "$((10#124000000 - 10#097000000))"
27000000
```

The problem is that, without the `10#` prefix, bash assumes that a number that starts with zero is octal.

Alternatively, use `bc`:

```
$ echo "124000000 - 097000000" | bc -l
27000000
```

Or use awk:

```
$ echo "124000000 097000000" | awk '{print $1-$2}'
27000000
```

#### Combining math and printf:

```
$ g=124000000
$ h=097000000
$ printf "Total time difference: %i milli seconds\n" "$(echo "$g - $h" | bc -l )"
Total time difference: 27000000 milli seconds
```

Or,

```
$ g=124000000
$ h=097000000
$ echo "$g $h" | awk '{printf "Total time difference: %i milliseconds\n",$1-$2}'; )
Total time difference: 27000000 milli seconds
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers.  A
>   leading 0x or 0X denotes hexadecimal.  Otherwise, numbers take the
>   form [base#]n, where the optional  base  is  a decimal  number 
>   between  2  and  64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a
>   number in that base.

#### Combining math and date

```
$ echo "$(( $(date -d '14:00:13.124' '+10#%s%N') - $(date -d '14:00:13.097' '+10#%s%N') ))"
27000000
```

If we want to convert from nanoseconds to milliseconds:

```
$ echo "$(( ($(date -d '14:00:13.124' '+10#%s%N') - $(date -d '14:00:13.097' '+10#%s%N'))/1000000 ))"
27

$ echo "$(( ($(date -d '14:00:05.320' '+10#%s%N') - $(date -d '14:00:04.909' '+10#%s%N'))/1000000 ))"
411
```

Comment: Hi, how we can use in given script I tried this in my script which get data from a file :                                                                                              g=$(( $(date -d 10#$d +%s) - $(date -d 10#$a +%s) ))
    h=$(( $(date -d 10#$d +%N) - $(date -d 10#$a +%N) ))  getting syntax error.

Comment: @VivekNigam See the example using date that I just added to the end of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Given command give output in milli second                     echo "$(( $(date -d '14:00:13.124' '+10#%N') - $(date -d '14:00:13.097' '+10#%N') ))"

Comment: 14:00:13,124 14:00:14,097                                                               Output is in minus : -27000000                                                              Not giving accurate result not taking minutes.

Comment: @VivekNigam (A) To convert from nanoseconds to milliseconds, we need to divide by 1,000,000.   See new example at end of answer.  (B)  As shown in the answer, I get a positive output.  If you are getting a negative output, try reversing the order of the numbers.

Comment: $echo "$(( ($(date -d '14:00:05.320' '+10#%N') - $(date -d '14:00:04.909' '+10#%N'))/1000000 ))"                                         Result is = -589 wrong answer

Comment: @VivekNigam Oops!  You're right.  See code in updated answer to avoid that.